# Get list of all installed Build Agents in TFS 2018

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

Is it possible to get a list of all Available Build Agents Installed?

I am using TFS 2018 and want to fetch the excel containing all build agents installed along their hosted Machine names. If it is possible, how?

Comment: Have you tried doing anything with your agent pool at `https://{your_server}/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool` as explained on the [Build and Release Agents MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts)?

Comment: I dont think so . I can only see agents in front of each build agent pool which is good but i am looking for list of all agent in all agent pools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below Powershell script to get the list of agents in all agent pools and export to excel (a `*.csv` file which can be opened in excel):

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password",
   [string]$path = "D:\temp" # Export the agent list (*.csv file) to this path

)

$filename = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + "-" + "AgentList.csv"

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get pools 
$poolsUrl = "$collectionurl/_apis/distributedtask/pools"            
$poolresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $poolsUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$pools = $poolresponse.value

foreach ($pool in $pools )
{
#Get agent list from pool
$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$($pool.id)/agents?includeCapabilities=true&includeAssignedRequest=true"         
$agentresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$agents = $agentresponse.value

$agentlist = @()

   foreach ($agent in $agents)
   {

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "PoolName" = $pool.name
          "Agent.Name" = $agent.systemCapabilities.'Agent.Name'
          "Agent.Version" = $agent.systemCapabilities.'Agent.Version'
          "Agent.ComputerName" = $agent.systemCapabilities.'Agent.ComputerName'
        } 

    $agentlist += $customObject
   }

   $agentlist | Select `
                PoolName,
                Agent.Name,
                Agent.Version, 
                Agent.ComputerName |export-csv -Path $path\$filename -NoTypeInformation -Append

}
```

[image]

Comment: YES , IT WORKED. THANK YOU!!

Comment: I have clicked it the link u sent. Any other Wat to accept answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Powershell script (with `Invoke-RestMethod`) to use REST Api and get the agents.

For example:

```
http://TFS-SERVER:8080/tfs/_apis/distributedtask/pools/1/agents?includeCapabilities=false&includeAssignedRequest=true
```

In the api above you will get all the agents in pool 1, you can iterate over all the pools id's and get the all agents, after that export the data to excel.

More information about `Invoke-RestMethod` of Powershell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6).